# How to implement screen lock for web page angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement LOck screen in my webpage using angularjs. Once user logs in using username and password he will be taken to user home page  where he has the  lock screen button. Once he clicks that button he should be taken to a page where the username is already set and the user has to enter only password.How to achieve this using angularjs ..please help, or tell some links where i get idea to achieve this.

I am developng application with springmvc and angularjs

Comment: Hi, are you implementig a One Page Application?

Comment: giulio-molinari: Yes

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little complex to be written in just one post, but I'll try to help you.

First of all, I suggest to take a look at **$cookieStore** and **$route**: the first is useful to maintain the application stateless; the second will be used to navigate throughout your application (correlated to the use of **ngView**).

You need three views: login, lock and home. All these are surrounded by a **common controller** (this controller will contain the ng-view directive) that will route based on $cookieStore variables. You should store basically two informations: username and lockFlag. The controller will route to:

- login view if username is empty;
- lock view if username is not empty and lockFlag is true;
- home view if username is not empty and lockFlag is empty or false.

The use of $cookieStore can be replaced with any other type of stateless storing method.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask. Bye!